# What was the dialogue (debate) between YajnaMurti and Ramanujacharya?

Tags: history, sri-vaishnava, ramanujacharya

While reading the biography of Sri Ramanujacharya, I've read one story of **YajnaMurti (यज्ञमूर्ति)**, (You can read it from [Internet Archive pg. 107](https://archive.org/details/HindiBook-shriRamanujacharya.kaJeevan.charit/page/n105)) who was the believer of Advaita. He was pundit of south India and taken Sanyasa on the bank of river Bhagirathi. After returning from north, he found that Ramanujacharya is propagating his doctrine by refuting Advaita. He immediately reached at Sri Rangam and asked for debate (शास्त्रार्थ​) with Ramanujacharya. *The debate started and continued for 17 days!* On the last day, Yajnamurti refuted logical arguments of Ramanujacharya. Although on the next day, upon the blessings/grace of [Varadaraja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varadharaja_Perumal_Temple,_Kanchipuram), Yajnamurti  (felling sorry) holded the feet of Ramanujacharya and became शिष्य​ (disciple) of him.

Do we have the dialogue or conversation of the debate happened between Yajnamurti and Ramanujacharya?

Comment: Then why no honorifics for yajnamoorti?